# How do I set a Word Checkbox using the Interop?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto

I can set string fields:

```
Dim msWord As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
```

This works fine:

```
doc.Bookmarks("InitialsSecurityClass108").Range.Text = _ WordDocDAta.InitialsSecurityClass108
```

But this doesn't work:

```
doc.Bookmarks("chkSecurityClass101").Range.Text = .chkSecurityClass101
```

I just want to check a box on my Word form. I can't even find the "Range" property.

I've searched:

1. Stack
2. the object browser in VS Studio
3. [Bookmarks Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.bookmarks?view=word-pia)

Comment: I should add that ".chkSecurityClass101" is a boolean and I've tried ".chkSecurityClass101.ToString"

Comment: Note that you can use the [edit] link below your question to add information to it. Comments are considered "ephemeral" on Stack Overflow, so it's better to have all relevant information in the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with form fields it's better to address the formfield object rather than the bookmark name. The bookmark name serves as the index value for the FormFields collection.

For example:

```
doc.FormFields("InitialsSecurityClass108").Result = "Text in textbox"
doc.FormFields("chkSecurityClass101").CheckBox.Value = true
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks much. Sure wish the MS docs for the Interop had code examples. I spent way too much time trying to find this answer before coming here.  Thanks again...

Comment: @djQuecke You might try going through the VBA Editor in the Office application: F2 for the object browser to search the term. Click on/in the term, then F1 to bring up the Help topic. The VBA help tends to have more code examples. You can't use them 1:1, of course, but for VB.NET it's very similar. In this particular case identical, actually...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be indicating there is a bookmark that surrounds a Checkbox Content Control in your document? If that is true then to mark the Checkbox you'll need code such as this ...

```
doc.Bookmarks("chkSecurityClass101").Range.ContentControls(1).Checked = True
```

Comment: They are CheckBox Form Fields. .ContentControls() does not seem to include any members in my doc. Are there different types of checkboxes? It appears maybe I have to replace Form Fields with ContentControl checkboxes?